# How to get metadata on another jsp?

Tags: liferay, metadata, liferay-6

I have a custom code for DL Portlet. The content uploaded of in DL folder displayed like this in below image. I want to display the metadata of each content on click of file name on another jsp.
Code used is:
 `<tr ng-repeat="f in files" ng-hide="f.deleted" class="animate-hide">
            <td><a title="{{f.name}}" ng-click="viewFile(f.id);">{{f.name}}</a></td>
            <td>{{f.size}}</td>
            <td>{{f.version}}</td>
            <td>{{f.permission}}</td>
            <td>{{f.lastChange}}</td>
            <td>{{f.downloadCount}}</td>
            <td ng-switch on="f.actions.length > 0">`
[image]
Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hook and customize..
when you onclick simple open jsp page in AUI dialog..

Have a look into following link for AUI Dialogs in Liferat

[working with AUI Dialog in Liferay](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/11/working-with-liferay-alloy-ui-dialogs.html)